# Windows XP control panel - providing a value for the "comments" field

Tags: windows-xp, controlpanel

Where does the Windows XP control panel get the value for the "Comments" field from? I'm writing an EXE control panel application, and it doesn't appear from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144195.aspx) that you can provide a value for that field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Registering an Executable File (exe) as a Control Panel Applet on Windows Vista using Windows Installer XML (WIX)* at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422220759/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/05/03/registering-an-executable-file-exe-as-a-control-panel-applet-on-windows-vista-using-windows-installer-xml-wix.aspx)

---

[previous answer]

See the *Executable Control Panel Item Registration* of *Registering Control Panel Items* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144195(VS.85).aspx

Specifically, you want `InfoTip`, which is the comments.

> *Registering Control Panel Items*
>
> Control Panel items must be registered
> in order to appear in the Control
> Panel window. If the Control Panel
> item is implemented as part of a .exe
> file then it is registered as a
> command object. Registration differs
> if the item is implemented as a .dll
> file that exports the CPlApplet
> function.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The contents of that field appear in the tooltip if you hover over the applet.

Comment: It turns out your original hint was the answer. I had the InfoTip set to "@(path),(index)", and setting it to "@(path),-(index)" made it work. I'm giving you the bounty because you had the right answer first. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, it is always something simple. :O)

Answer (score 1):

[Using CPLApplet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> When Control Panel loads a .dll (or
>   .cpl) file, it calls the CPlApplet
>   function to get information such as
>   the number of Control Panel items the
>   file hosts, **as well as information
>   about each item**.
>
> When Windows first loads the Control
>   Panel item, it retrieves the address
>   of the **CPlApplet** function and
>   subsequently uses that address to call
>   the function and pass it messages. It
>   might send the following messages.

You need to handle [CPL_INQUIRE Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787980%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and fill the [CPLINFO Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773239%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
typedef struct tagCPLINFO {
  int      idIcon;
  int      idName;
  int      idInfo;
  LONG_PTR lpData;
} CPLINFO;
```

`idInfo` is the resource identifier of the string containing the description. You cannot simply set this thing by filling in some registry key.

**Edit:** Ok, my bad, this is an old solution.

Comment: Yes, this was working before when we installed by copying a .cpl file to system32. We converted to an EXE file in the Program Files area for a variety of reasons, and I wondered if we could get this back.

Answer (score 1):

This string is retrieved from the HKCR\CLSID{guid}\InfoTip registry value.  How to whack the registry into shape is explained very well in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144195%28VS.85%29.aspx), not much I can add to that.